# Can you bind mouse keys (i.e. use one of the buttons instead of shift)

Tags: customization

I've tried searching for this but can't see any solutions for the newer versions. Basically, I want to assign one of my extra mouse buttons to be 'shift' so I can pan without touching the keyboard. I have a middle mouse button and then two extra ones on the side.

It seemed older versions this was easy, but I've got Blender 3.4.1 and this seems to have removed the ability to customise key binds? Let me know if I'm just missing something obvious, or whether this is actually a bad idea for some reason I don't understand because I'm a beginner at Blender.

I have a Logitech G203 Lightsync mouse and running on Windows 10 Pro if this helps at all.

Edit: Managed to solve the issue with a lot of trial and error for anyone else who is confused. Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Keymap -> type 'pan' to filter the results in the search bar -> look for 3D View -> Reassign the pan view to the button you want to assign it to.

Comment: "*Seems to have removed the ability to customise key binds?*" They didn't. "*I want to assign one of my extra mouse buttons to be 'shift' so I can pan*" This sounds like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why not assign the mouse button to pan directly? You can still assign arbitrary keys as "modifiers" in Blender 3.6, but you apparently can't have both be combinations of mouse keys.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, apologies because I guess I wasn't clear enough, but how do I reassign the pan function to a mouse button?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would go to that Blender version's USER directory and delete everything in there, then pickup a fresh Blender from blender.org and reinstall Blender.

USER directories:

- Linux: `$HOME/.config/blender/`
- MacOS: `/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Blender/`
- Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\`

[Blender’s Directory Layout — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html#macos)